# ODBC data transfer to SQL server

Tags: odbc-sql-server-driver

How does the ODBC driver transfer data between an application to MSSQL Server 2005?

Is it serialized?

I'm trying to send data between SQL Server 2005 & MS Dynamics 4.0 but I suspect my data is altered by the ODBC driver in between.

Comment: You should accept and mark up answers that solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its sent as a wide-character string to SQL server -- i.e., a SQL query batch. No transformation needs to take place. The return data is structured in a protocol called TDS.

I believe if you are using the ASCII functions of the ODBC native client it gets upscalled to wide-character.

Comment: so sending a date from AX4.0 to SQL Server in this format DD/MM/YYYY would still be exactly that at other end?

Comment: yes, it should be exactly the same. I have looked at the protocol a few years ago using wireshark :D.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the date formats on the 2 servers, you may have issues with localisation/regional settings

Comment: I'm sending the date using ODBCConnection X++ class in AX Client to SQL Server, so where would I look for the setting you're talking about?  Sorry I'm new to AX...